# compiling various header files in c using autotools in arch linux

Tags: c, linux, linker, header-files, autotools

i would like to know how can i compile a number of header files by just one command using autotools in arch linux

Answer (score 1):

Header files are not for compilation. They do not (or should not) define an implementation.

For general automake help, I would suggest the [Automake manual](http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't compile header files (`.h`), but instead the `.c` files.

If you just have some source code package that uses autotools and that you want to compile the usual command would be:

```
./configure && make
```

If you also want to install the package an your system, follow that up by `make install`.

Comment: all my c files are linked to eack other if i make a change in one of the c files, while compilation gcc compiles all the c files linked to it, which consumes alot of time. So could u kindly tell me wat can i do bout it?